# C++ Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a question about this syntax regarding initialization.

Quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

```
X a = X();
// valid given X(const X& copy_from_me) but not valid given X(X& copy_from_me)               
// because the second wants a non-const X&               
// to create a, the compiler first creates a temporary by invoking the default constructor               
// of X, then uses the copy constructor to initialize a as a copy of that temporary.                
// However, for some compilers both the first and the second actually work.
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Default Constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Assignment operator called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo b = Foo(); //case 1:default 
    Foo c = Foo(a); //case 2: copy constructor
}
```

Case 1:
Upon changing the parameter from const to non const in the copy constructor, case 1 won't compile as expected from wikipedia. However, when ran using the proper copy constructor, it only calls the default constructor. Why doesn't it also call the copy constructor? Is this an optimization done at compile-time?

Case 2:
The answer to case 1 will probably answer case 2 for me, but why does this only call the copy constructor once?

Comment: "*Is this an optimization done at compile-time?*" It's called [_copy elision_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) -- read up. :-]

Answer (score 4):

```
Foo b = Foo();
```

This form requires a valid matching copy constructor to exist, but the copy may be optimized away.  The fact that it may be optimized away does not relax the requirement that the constructor exist though.

By making your copy constructor take a non-const reference, it no longer matches, since `Foo()` generates a temporary, and temporaries cannot bind to non-const references.  When you make the parameter const reference(or scrap your copy c-tor and use the compiler generated copy c-tor), then it works, because temporaries can bind to const references.

Comment: If the c-ctor doesn't exist, the compiler generates one, so that's not really a requirement...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If the compiler generates one, then it exists.

Comment: Well yeah, but that makes the statement redundant - unless you specify that a compiler-generated one will exist.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Makes which statement redundant?

Comment: Your last statement. I think it *might* be confusing for a beginner. If I was reading it as a beginner, I'd think I'd have to define a copy constructor for this to compile...

Answer (score 1):

`X()` is a temporary, so you can't bind it to a non-`const` reference (although MSVS has an extension that allows it).

1) Yes, it's a compiler optimization

2) Illegal, because `a` doesn't exist. But in principle, again, yes, a compiler optimization.